# What is the probability that he/she has a score greater than $90$?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> Exam scores of a placement test is known to be normally distributed with mean $78$
> and standard deviation $3$. Suppose a candidate is randomly selected from a sample
> of $100$.
>
> a) What is the probability that he/she has a score greater than $90$?

Here what I thought,

First I want to find $\theta=P(X>90)$ using $Z=\frac{X-78}{3}$ now by the binomial distribution required probability  $P(x=1)={100 \choose 1}\theta(1-\theta)^{99}  $

I saw $\theta=P(X>90)\approx 0$ so how do I find the probability?
Can anyone tell me whether this is correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

The probability $P(x=1)$ you calculated in your post, can be seen as a the probability that exactly $1$ person has a score greater than $90$ and the other $99$ persons have a score below $90$, which is not what we're looking for when we want to answer a).

For answering a) the information that you take one person out of a sample of $100$ is not really needed, because informally you can think of the random variable $X$ as picking a random person and measuring his/her exam score. It does not matter how big/small the sample is. The only information that is needed is the distribution of $X$, which is the normal distribution.

So the answer to a) would be: $P(X>90)=P(\frac{X-78}{3}>4)=1-P(Z\leq 4)=1-0,99997$. With $Z$ being standard normal.